# Can videos be played offline from file storage with Javascript app frameworks?

Tags: android, ios, ionic2, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

My organization (a video library) is looking into building an app version of our product, and I am very interested in using JavaScript-based framework, both to increase development time, lower costs, and take advantage of our in-house expertise in Angular.  We are currently looking at Nativescript and Ionic 2/Cordova as possibilities.  Both seem good, but we have one specific requirement, for which I haven't found any relevant information: Is it possible, using either of these frameworks, to download videos to a client's file storage and play them offline?  Ideally, when downloaded, the files would be encrypted in such as a way as to prevent users from taking the files (they would be decrypted by the offline player)?  I need to present some options for our executive team, so any information as to whether these frameworks can offer this functionality would be helpful.

Comment: Saving an .mp4 or other file to the device using a file system process is possible on NS for sure and I believe Cordova has a file system module as well. So I can't think of a reason either would prevent this from working. I know on NS it's possible, cannot confirm the approach on Cordova.

Comment: Encrypting and decrypting the file (in memory most likely) prior to playing it will likely have to be a custom implementation. Join the fine people at https://discourse.nativescript.org/ with any other questions you may have.